# How to make a grid view with different item sizes adjusted to different sizes?

Tags: iphone, gridview

I am trying to do make a grid view with boxes (item) of different sizes (three types) i have implemented this

https://github.com/tanin47/UIGridView

but cant really make three different types of cells and align them in the gridview.

I am trying to call different cells like this:

```
- (UIGridViewCell *) gridView:(UIGridView *)grid cellForRowAt:(int)rowIndex AndColumnAt:(int)columnIndex
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [testArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex * 2 +columnIndex] ;


    if ([[dic objectForKey:@"type"] isEqualToString:@"one"]) {
        Cell *cell = (Cell *)[grid dequeueReusableCell];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[Cell alloc] init];
        }
        NSLog(@"dic:%@",dic);
        //  cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d,%d)", rowIndex, columnIndex];
        cell.label.text = [dic objectForKey:@"handa"];
        return cell;

    }
    else {
        CellTpye2 *cell = (CellTpye2 *)[grid dequeueReusableCell];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[CellTpye2 alloc] init];
        }

        NSLog(@"dic:%@",dic);
        //  cell.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d,%d)", rowIndex, columnIndex];
        cell.label.text = [dic objectForKey:@"handa"];
        return cell;
    }


}
```

M i doing the call right, can this be done in the this grid view.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Nope i made one cell only with 20 different layers on it to represent specific case also with dynamic different heights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uicollectionview insets solved the problem sorry for late update